# add <sup></sup> on last digit of number for json array

Tags: jquery, json

```
    [{"dir":"down","sym":"oo","b":"1.35553","a":"1.35556"},
    {"dir":"down","sym":"pp","b":"1.64442","a":"1.64451"},
    {"dir":"down","sym":"qq","b":"104.603","a":"104.609"},
    {"dir":"up","sym":"rr","b":"0.88186","a":"0.88191"},
    {"dir":"up","sym":"ss","b":"1.09667","a":"1.09672"}]
```

from the above json i need to add  for the b & a both last digit number using jquery , my jquery is

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(window).load(function(){
    setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        cache: false,
            url: 'get.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json){
            var dd="";
            for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++){
                if(json[i].dir == 'up'){
             var ii= '<img src="img/up.gif" />';        
            } else {
            var ii= '<img src="img/down.gif" />';       
            }
                dd += ii + '-' + json[i].sym+ '-' + json[i].b+ '-' + json[i].a+'--';
            }
    $('#divToRefresh').html(dd);
        }
    });
    }, 1000); 
    });
    </script>
```

i need like this example :

```
     json[0].b="1.35553";
     json[0].a="1.35556";
```

how i get like above example from the json code through jquery, any idea..

Comment: What is your code outputting at the moment?

Comment: json[0].b="1.35553";
json[0].a="1.35556";

Comment: Please provide information about what you have tried and why it didn't work, your code doesn't show any attempt to solve your problem yet – SO is a platform to seek help, not to let others do your work :/

Comment: @Bala update your question with that. Try not to put code in the comments section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
var a = 1.35556.toString();
var start = a.substr(0, a.length-1);
var end = a.substr(-1);
console.log(start + end.sup()); // 1.3555<sup>6</sup>
```

Comment: Or shorter: `start + end.sup()`
[sup() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/sup)